# Change sidebar headers from H1?

Tags: sidebar, title, seo

My theme uses H1 tags without much thought, including the site name at the top of each page and each of the sidebar menu titles. I checked the sidebar.php file in my themes folder, but there is no HTML content present.

```
<?php
/**
 * The sidebar containing the main widget area.
 *
 * @package Button
 */

if ( ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) {
    return;
}
?>

<div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">

    <?php if ( has_nav_menu ( 'social' ) ) : ?>
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location'  => 'social',
            'depth'           => 1,
            'link_before'     => '<span class="screen-reader-text">',
            'link_after'      => '</span>',
            'container_class' => 'social-links',
        ) ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
</div><!-- #secondary -->
```

What file would the HTML layout be stored in so I can change those?

Comment: Check for the `register_sidebar()` part in the theme files, this is usually where it is set via `before_title` & `after_title`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tags used for the headings would be set wherever the sidebars are registered. Look for `register_sidebar()` in the theme's functions.php file (or a file that has been included into the functions file).

It will look like this (example from [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_sidebar/#comment-366)):

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'textdomain' ),
    'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
    'description'   => __( 'Widgets in this area will be shown on all posts and pages.', 'textdomain' ),
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</li>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>',
) );
```

Just change the tag in `before_title` and `after_title`.

For what it's worth, and just in my opinion, the 'only one h1 tag' thing is just a superstition of so-called SEO experts and there's probably nothing wrong with having h1 tags in the sidebar. What's more important is the *hierarchy* of the headings. If the headings in the sidebar don't make sense as subheadings of the main h1, then they shouldn't be marked up as such. If you use the [W3C Markup Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) with "Show Outline" enabled you can see a heading-level outline of the page. That outline should make logical sense, and sometimes more than one h1  is the way to achieve that.

Comment: I did indeed find it in the functions.php and changed them over to H2 for the time being. While I do agree that it is probably not an issue, the change is still logical from a screen reader standpoint. I used the W3C Markup tool and actually fixed some other errors I didn't even know existed (stray tags and what not). Thank you for the help!